# Change color of one variable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe

```
> head(sample_data_df)

             Gene_1     Gene_2      Gene_3     Gene_4     Gene_5
Sample_1 -1.1698306  1.2408295  1.42964624 -0.2323205  0.1669285
Sample_2 -0.6983788 -0.9224843  2.21307158 -0.3003344 -0.5299774
[...]
```

that I melt with

```
sample_data_melt <- melt(sample_data_df)

  variable      value
1   Gene_1 -1.1698306
2   Gene_1 -0.6983788
```

and plot with

```
ggplot(sample_data_melt, aes(x=variable,y=value)) + 
  geom_point(position = "jitter")
```

I would like to change the alpha of all samples (rows in `sample_data_df`) to be 0.5 except for one sample. I know I can set it different per point by making an alpha vector like

```
alpha <- rep(0.1,5005)
alpha[seq(0, 5005, by= 1001)] <- 1
ggplot(sample_data_melt, aes(x=variable,y=value)) + 
  geom_point(position = "jitter",alpha = alpha)
```

but how do I set one specific sample as alpha 1?

Comment: could you just subset for this sample and then add a second geom_point(..alpha=1)

Comment: @MLavoie so subset before the melt and then do it twice or how?

Comment: sample_data_melt_s <- sample_data_melt %>% filter(value==valueyouwant); ....+ geom_point(data= sample_data_melt_s, aes(x=variable,y=value), alpha=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is valuable information in the row names that gets lost when you melt (the sample numbers). I'd recommend keeping this around:

```
sample_data_df$sample = row.names(sample_data_df)
sample_data_melt = melt(sample_data_df, id.vars = "sample")
```

You can then set an indicator for the sample you want to be fully opaque

```
sample_data_melt$alpha = ifelse(sample_data_melt$sample == "Sample_2", "Sample 2", "Other")
```

And map that to alpha in your plot:

```
ggplot(sample_data_melt, aes(x=variable,y=value)) + 
    geom_point(aes(alpha = alpha), position = "jitter") +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.5, 1))
```

(Untested as your data isn't shared reproducibly, please use `dput()` or simulate data if you want tested answers.)